# Is general and special relatively a consequence of Maxwells equations?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, maxwell-equations

It seems, more or less that,

special relativity simply states the effect on space and time assuming that Maxwell's equations hold true everywhere, and

general relativity...

...well I was thinking it was a consequence of considering gravity in light of special relativity or maxwell's equations but now it seems Einstein kinda pulled this one out of no where.

Are special and general theories of relativity a consequence of Maxwell's equations?

Another way of asking this: Is the first part stated above true and how or what relationship General Relativity has with Maxwell's equations?

Comment: I’m not conversant in SR and GR, but as I recall Einstein refers to Maxwells equations in his 1905 paper “On the Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies”.

Comment: But I don’t recall it being part of the impetus of GR. That I thought was the equivalence principle

Comment: @BobD, Is the equivalence principle is the main theoretical argument for General Relativity made by Einstein?

Comment: As I understand it, it was more an inspiration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is general and special relatively a consequence of Maxwells equations?

No. Neither is a consequence. You can have both Special Relativity and General Relativity without having electromagnetism and Maxwell’s equations.

The relativity theories are theories about the geometry of spacetime. Electromagnetism is a theory about one particular interaction taking place *in* spacetime. EM doesn’t make sense without spacetime, but spacetime does makes sense without EM.

> How or what relationship General Relativity has with Maxwell's equations?

Maxwell’s equations can be [formulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations_in_curved_spacetime) in curved spacetime so that they are compatible with General Relativity.

The original versions of Maxwell’s equations are form-invariant under Lorentz transformations. Historically, this was a clue toward the development of Special Relativity.

Comment: Was special theory of relativity developed to explain the discrepancies between the Lorentz invariant Maxwell equations with Newtonian based transformation of coordinates? In other words the Moving Magnet and Conductor problem?

Comment: I’m not much of an expert on the history of physics, but I would say that SR made physicists accept the “physicality” of the Lorentz transformations and their implications for space and time (as opposed to these transformations just being mathematical symmetries of Maxwell’s equations), and SR reformulated classical mechanics (velocity, momentum, acceleration, force, energy, Newton’s Laws, etc.) to be consistent with these transformations rather than with Galilean transformations.

Comment: Oh, so maybe this aspect of Maxwell's equations is more so related to special relativity the way that mercury's orbit and other observations are to general relativity. Aka supporting evidence in a way. Thanks!